# Embedded python code in Bottle template - simple comparison using "if" statement

Tags: python, bottle

I have following bottle template code to show my table:

```
<tbody>
    %for row in rows:
    <tr>
        %for col in row:
        <td>{{col}}</td>
        %end
    </tr>
    %end
</tbody>
```

I would like to check all my cells and change their look if they do not contain "Some string":

```
if col == "Some string":
    <td>{{col}}</td>
else:
    <td class="table-danger">{{col}}</td>
```

Do I need to do comparisons in a template (frontend) or in my "engine" (backend)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in template like :

```
    <tbody>
        %for row in rows:
        <tr>
            %for col in row:
            <td {{'class=table-danger' if col == "Some string" else ""}}>
              {{col}}
            </td>
            %end
        </tr>
        %end
    </tbody>
```

Comment: I have just modified that line: <td {{'class=table-danger' if col == "Some string" else ""}}>. It seems to work well!

Comment: @Sharpowski ok great so just verify answer so it can be helpful to others as well.